# Passwordless login in Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: ssh, login, 23.04

I created my public key and successfully transformed it to my remote computer, but it still asks password while trying to connect it with SSH. It worked fine on the previous version of Ubuntu 21.04 or later but not on 23.04 or 22.10.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. To clarify, you would like your SSH key on your desktop to be used as the method to log into your server?

Comment: My guess it's probably something you've done strangely; as I've noted no differences in *lunar* and prior releases. I just tried *passwordless* login into this *lunar* install & it worked perfectly just as it did for me on 22.10 (*kinetic*) & even 21.04 (*hirsute*) & I made no changes between then... Instead your details as provided imply you've done things out of the ordinary anyway (21.04 had no *supported* upgrade path to *lunar* (23.04) for example). FYI: This setup was created in *artful* though the PC died end of *hirsute*; thus it was a new *lunar* install except for my backup configs.

Comment: Just to confirm, did you try the command `ssh -i /path/to/public.key username@ip.address` ?